# PSQL aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql, group-by

I'm in an SQL class in college and we are using PSQL.

Tables for reference.

```
     Table "public.author"
   Column   |  Type   | Modifiers 
------------+---------+-----------
 au_id      | numeric | not null
 first_name | text    | not null
 last_name  | text    | not null
 year_born  | numeric | not null

     Table "public.book"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------+---------+-----------
 title  | text    | not null
 year   | numeric | not null
 isbn   | text    | not null
 pub_id | numeric | not null
```

Problem I'm stuck on is:
Display author names, book titles, and publication year for all the books published from 1990 to 1993, inclusive. Display the author names as Last, First (with a comma and space between). Sort the output by publication year.

Output:

```
select concat(last_name, ',', first_name) as name, title, year from author, book where year >= 1990 and year <= 1993 group by year order by year;
```

> ERROR:  column "author.last_name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
>   LINE 1: select concat(last_name, ',', first_name) as name, title, ye...

I get that it's saying I need to have that in the order, but the problem asks that I order by the year ranges.

Comment: Why are do you even use `GROUP BY`? I cannot see a need for it. But you're missing a join criteria between `author` and `book`. And you probably should rather use the explicit `author INNER JOIN book ON ...` syntax -- easier to read, easier to understand and the error would have been obvious with it.

Comment: @stickybit I was using `GROUP BY` because everything we've done in class so far led me to believe it was necessary. We have not covered `INNER JOIN` yet so I'm not sure it would be applicable to this problem(which you couldn't have known). I took off the `GROUP BY` and the terminal is hung up now:
`select concat(last_name, ',', first_name) as name, title, year from author, book where year >= 1990 and year <= 1993 order by year;`

Comment: There are no keys linking `author` and `book`.  You cannot do what you want with these two tables.

Answer (score 0):

The error: a `GROUP BY` clause is only neccessary if you have one or more aggregate columns (like sum, max, min, avg) and you need to add all other columns in the `GROUP BY` clause.

What you have tried: cross join all books with all authors and display a large result set.
I assume the author_id of the book is in column `pub_id` of table book and the same id is in author.au_id.
If you do not use `INNER JOIN ...` you can place the join condition inside `WHERE`statement: `WHERE author.au_id=book.pub_id   and year >= 1990 and year <= 1993`

Answer (score 0):

While doing query with two tables refer the particular table using the "." and when u get an error

ERROR: column "author.last_name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause

Include author.last_name also in the group by statement,like i have included Author_name in the below code.

```
select concat(author.last_name, ',', author.first_name) as 
Author_name,book.title,book.year
from author,book
where book.year >= 1990 and book.year <= 1993
group by book.year,book.title,Author_name
order by book.year asc;
```

Answer (score 0):

The two tables that you have are not sufficient for this question.  You need a junction table, with one row per author and book.  Let me call this `book_authors`.

Then, this query would be written as:

```
select concat(a.last_name, ',', a.first_name) as name, b.title, b.year
from author a join
     book_authors ba
     on a.au_id = ba.au_id join
     book b
     on b.isbn = ba.isbn
where b.year >= 1990 and b.year <= 1993 
order by b.year;
```

Notes:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.  It is very, very sad if a class in 2018 is teaching outdated syntax.
- `GROUP BY` does not appear to be needed for this query.
- Use table aliases that are abbreviations of the table names.
- Qualify all column references (that is, include the table name in the reference).